# Meta-Analysis - Calculating SE from given ES

Tags: standard-error, meta-analysis

I have the following problem. I am trying to conduct a meta-analysis and I have an effect size estimation of some unpublished studies. Unfortunately, I don't have the Standard Errors for the mentioned Effect sizes.

Is it possible to calculate the Standard Error for the given Effect size?

Kind regards,
Martha

Comment: Could you describe in your post what kind of effect sizes you’re working with? Correlations? Mean differences?

Comment: I use mean differences. Effect size is Hedge g.

Comment: Do you have the sample sizes?

Comment: I have the number of the total sample size

Comment: I think there is no reliable way to get the exact SE. However, you can impute it, or assume a worst or best case scenario and try different analyses...

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked, are these $g$ from independent groups or is it repeated measures from pre- post-?

Comment: Please see my answer to a similar question before (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/91313/24137). Simply stated, unless the authors give you the measure of variance, you can run several scenarios using imputed data. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! They are of great help!

Answer (score 1):

Let us work in terms of Cohen's $d$ and then convert to $g$.

It is known that the variance of $d$ is
$$
V_d = \frac{n_1 + n_2}{n_1n_2} + \frac{d^2}{2(n_1 + n_2)}
$$
where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the sample sizes per group.

Suppose we in fact have $g$, we know that
$$
g = J d
$$
where
$$
J = 1 - \frac{3}{4\nu - 1}
$$
where $\nu$ is the df, that is $n_1 + n_2 - 2$
and
$$
V_g = J^2 V_d
$$

So by backcalculation from $g$ to $d$, computing the variance there and then converting back we get the sampling variance for $g$. The required standard error is then the square root. If only the overall sample size is known then setting $n_1 = n_2 = n/2$ would be defensible.

Comment: If Hedge g is derived from data based on correlations, would I split the ntotal into n1 and n2?

Comment: No, that is a different situation. But why not meta-analyse the correlations (transformed using Fisher's $z$ transformation?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the original data. Its unpublished data and I have only access to the Effect size of the study (Hedge g) and if the sutdy used categorial or correlational data

Comment: The problem is that I was answering under the assumption that the primary studies involved two group comparisons but now it seems that they involved a single group measured twice. In that case, if it is true, my answer does not apply.

Comment: No its actually mixed. I have some studies that involve two group comparisons - for this studies your suggested convertations should work. But I have also studies that used correlations. If I understood correctly it is not possible to derive SE from this studies (with given g)?